# TypeError: explore() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, tkinter

My code

```
def explore(path):
# explorer would choke on forward slashes
path = os.path.normpath(path)

if os.path.isdir(path):
    subprocess.run([FILEBROWSER_PATH, path])
elif os.path.isfile(path):
    subprocess.run([FILEBROWSER_PATH, '/select,', os.path.normpath(path)])'
```

my error is

```
'TypeError: explore() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path''

message_button = Button(text="upload", command=explore)
message_button.grid(row=0,column=5, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
```

Comment: please put your code in the question :)

Comment: Just did, sorry :D

Comment: Hi!, you are missing the part in which you are calling the explore function, could you add that? :),

Also, there seems to be an indentation issue under def explore(path):, maybe it was when pasted here, maybe it would be better if you add the complete code of the file

Comment: Just added it! 

message_button = Button(text="upload", command=explore)
message_button.grid(row=0,column=5, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

Comment: I am also using this as part of the code

FILEBROWSER_PATH = os.path.join(os.getenv('WINDIR', "not found"), 'explorer.exe')

Comment: Your `explore` function needs to read the path from whatever tkinter textbox it resides in.  That's the problem.  Clicking the button just calls `explore()`, with no parameters.

Comment: Could you fix the formatting of your code?

Answer (score 0):

First, `explore` function takes an argument named `path`. But in the Button definition, there is no argument provided. However, you have not provided full code so that we could know how you get the path to use as an argument for `explore` function. So I would just assume that you somehow have a `mypath` variable that contains the path you want to *explore*.
You can fix this issue in different ways.

**1. By using Lambda definition or partial**

Using Lambda-

```
btn = Button(text="Upload", command = lambda path = mypath: explore(path))
```

Here, we put a default argument for the lambda function, and it calls the `explore` function using the `path` argument.

Using partial-

```
from functools import partial
btn = Button(master, text="Upload", command = partial(explore, mypath))
```

However, this approach wouldn't be very beneficial if your path changes dynamically.

**2. Modifying `explore` to handle dynamic inputs itself**

Here, I will assume that you have a text widget that takes the path as an input from the user and uses that for explore function.

```
...

textfield = Text()

def explore():
    path = textfield.get(0.0, END).strip()
    # explorer would choke on forward slashes
    path = os.path.normpath(path)

    if os.path.isdir(path):
        subprocess.run([FILEBROWSER_PATH, path])
    elif os.path.isfile(path):
        subprocess.run([FILEBROWSER_PATH, '/select,', os.path.normpath(path)])

btn = Button(text="Upload", command=explore)

...
```